# Abbreviation for EventArgs

Tags: c#, abbreviation

Is there a possibility to declare an abbreviation for some types like `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` so the lines don't get too long?

I have a method declared like this:

```
static void HtmlChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

Now I was thinking of a way to declare an abbreviation for the `EventArgs`. I tried it with `using`:

```
using DPCEA = DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs;
```

However, that doesn't work. I get the following exception:

> The type or namespace name 'DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs' could not be found.

I'd like to be able to declare my method like this:

```
static void HtmlChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DPCEA e)
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: When using `using` you need to use the full namespace: `using DPCEA = System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `using` statements, you need to give the full type name, including namespace:

```
using DPCEA = System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs;
```

Note that you have to repeat this in every file, so it might get tiresome and a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't think about that.. thank you.